# How to convert X, Y data-types to double value in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

I'm working with JavaFX and I'm creating a generic LineChart that can receive "String" or "Number" data types to the Axis, but I have a problem with the data types X, Y that I'm using because in the method to add data to the chart, I have two generic parameters X and Y, and I need convert "Y" to "double" because when I use this method the Y parameter is a "double" value, but I not can convert again "Y" value to "double".

The method to add data is:

```
    public void addData(final String idSeries, final X x, final Y y, String kindOfSymbol) {
        //valido que exista la serie
        boolean seriesExist = seriesMap.containsKey(idSeries);
        //obtengo el index de la serie, como fue almacenada en la grafica
        Integer indexSerie = seriesMap.get(idSeries);
        if (seriesExist) {
            Platform.runLater(() - > {
                XYChart.Series < X, Y > currentSeries = null;
                currentSeries = chart.getData().get(indexSerie.intValue());
                int lastNodePosition = currentSeries.getData().size() - 1;

                XYChart.Data < X, Y > point = new XYChart.Data < > (x, y);
//The problem is here when I try to convert "Y" to "double" because the object JFXStackPaneSymbol require the double and Dimension parameters
                point.setNode(new JFXStackPaneSymbol(y, new Dimension(15, 15)));
                currentSeries.getData().add(point);
                currentSeries.getData().get(lastNodePosition).getNode().setStyle(kindOfSymbol);
            });
        }
    }
```

the method invocation is:

```
lineChart.addData(Constants.ID_LINE_SERIE, xAxisUnit++, value, tempSymbol);
//Constants.ID_LINE_SERIE = String
//xAxisUnit++ = double
//value = double
//tempSymbol = String
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can You show with declaration?

Comment: EDIT: declaration of class, types X,Y etc

Comment: The X, Y data-types is part of JavaFX.. Look the class declaration.... public class JFXPanelLineChart < X, Y > extends JFXPanel {
 private Scene scene;
 private LineChart < X, Y > chart;

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it will be difficult to make a suggestion. Never heard about a class JFXStackPaneSymbol? So please make a suitable and runnable example.

Comment: JFXStackPaneSymbol is a custom class, is not a part of JavaFX. But simply require a double value that I need to retrieve of Y parameter.

Comment: The problem is how to convert Y parameter to double value. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: How do you instantiate the class with the method addData holding? If you extend a XYChart, and you probably instantiate it with `<Double, Double>`, then you may be able to switch to `<X, Y extends Double>` in you method class declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

Double.parseDouble(y.toString())

In the code is:

```
point.setNode(new JFXStackPaneSymbol(Double.parseDouble(y.toString()), new Dimension(15, 15)));
```